# External App wants to link to EditForm.aspx; need correct ID

Tags: 2010, soap

We have some limited SharePoint data in an external application; one of the fields we store in this outside application is "sharepointId" which has values like `{3FC51B00-543F-48E7-B774-403140B0BE56}`, taken from SharePoint SOAP services in the `ows_GUID` field.

Mostly, `EditForm.aspx` seems like it wants the `ID` field with an integer identifier for that item in the list, with URLs of the form `https://sharepoint/sites/My-Site/MyLibrary/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=1397`

So clearly this external system doesn't have the right integer IDs necessary to generate those links.  The question is:   is it possible to generate a URL if you know only the `GUID`, host, and list name?

Answer (score 0):

Use Title to store your GUID. 

Both ID and Title can be used in EditForm.aspx parameter, for example: 
https://sharepoint/sites/My-Site/MyLibrary/Forms/EditForm.aspx?Title=3FC51B00-543F-48E7-B774-403140B0BE56